# Custom fields when creating Shopify accounts using the API

Tags: php, shopify

I want to add some custom fields to the customer accounts in shopify using the API and then access them on the account page, how can I do that?  I see how to create accounts at http://wiki.shopify.com/Customer_%28API%29#Create_a_new_customer_account but can I add an arbitrary field to the request body somewhere?
Thank you

Comment: It doesn't look like the api is designed to submit custom fields to your account, you can only appear to get or submit information into the selected fields

Comment: Hi Rob, I found where you can add custom fields - see http://api.shopify.com/customer.html#create and scroll down to the example labeled "Create a new customer with a metafield".  Now I just need to figure out how to retrieve a metafield in the account template, does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHA!  I found where the custom metafields are described - http://www.shopify.com/technology/3032322-new-feature-metafields.  On that page is where the syntax for retrieving them in a liquid template is described, and the specifics for creating them from the API are at api.shopify.com/customer.html#create under the example labeled "Create a new customer with a metafield".